# What is the formula of this integral calculation?

Tags: integration

What is the formula used between these two steps?

$$
\int \left[(2xy^2+2x^3y^2)e^{x^2}+(2y+4x^2y)e^{x^2}+(xy^4)e^{x^2}\right] dx\\
 = x^2y^2e^{x^2}+2xye^{x^2}+\frac 12ye^{x^2} + C
$$

*(integration with respect to x, keeping y as constant)*

Comment: It's just the chain rule.

Answer (score 0):

It's... the integration by parts together with integration by substitution.

For example, the last piece:

$$\int xy^4 e^{x^2}\ dx$$

Use $x^2 = t$; $dt = 2x dx$ hence $dx = \frac{dt}{2x} = \frac{dt}{2\sqrt{t}}$

That is,

$$\int \sqrt{t}y^4 e^t \frac{dt}{2\sqrt{t}} = \frac{y^4}{2}\int e^t dt = \frac{y^4}{2} e^t$$

Going back to $x$:

$$\frac{y^4}{2} e^{x^2}$$

And so on for the other terms.

Comment: what about $ye^{x^2}$ term?

Comment: @daulomb This is just a piece, to show the OP the method.

Comment: yes you're right there may be some typo regards

Comment: Then it is long time calculation, it shouldn't have come in such exams where I have only 10-15 minutes to complete this math, and this is only a part of the full math, I'm finding primitive of an ODE.

Comment: @DG_ To do the whole integral it won't take you more than 5 minutes, actually...